# ¿ como imprimo en pantalla las variables que especifico dentro dela funcion?

Tags: javascript

tengo esta funcion
pero quiero imprimir en consola el resultado de var min y var max; como daria ordenes para esto en javascrip

```
let list = [4,6,2,1,9,63,-134,566]; 

var min = function(list)
{
    list.sort((a, b) => (a - b)); return list[0]; 
} 

var max = function(list)
{ 
    list.sort((a, b) => (b - a)); return list[0]; 
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para imprimir en consola se utiliza la función "log" del objeto "console".

Por lo que para imprimir los valores deseados debería quedarte de la siguiente manera.

```
console.log(min(list))
console.log(max(list))
```

Saludos

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: Eesto lo neceista muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que intentas es obtener de un array el numero mayor y menor, te dejo el siguiente algoritmo que hice, en este caso esta validado tanto para si tienes números positivos como negativos, de igual forma se puede acortar un poco más;

Aqui puedes verlo funcionando:

https://codepen.io/jonath4n/pen/xxWQmwq?editors=0011

```
let list = [4,6,2,1,9,63,-134,566]; 

//Obtener numeros negativos y positivos
const setNumbers = () =>
{
  let positiveNumbers = [];
  let negativeNumbers = [];
  
  //Filtro de numeros positivos y negativos
  list.map(num => 
  {
     if(num > -1)
     {
       positiveNumbers.push(num);
     }
      else
     {
       negativeNumbers.push(num);
     }
  });
  
  //Define min, max
  let min, max;
  
  //Existen numeros positivos y negativos
  if(positiveNumbers.length > 0 && negativeNumbers.length > 0)
  {
    min = Math.min(...negativeNumbers);
    max = Math.max(...positiveNumbers);
    
    return `El numero mayor es ${max} y el menor es ${min}`;
  }

  //Existen numeros positivos solamente
  if(positiveNumbers.length > 0 && negativeNumbers.length == 0)
  {
    max = Math.max(...positiveNumbers);
    
    return `El numero mayor es ${max}`;
  }

  //Existen numeros negativos solamente
  if(positiveNumbers.length == 0 && negativeNumbers.length > 0)
  {
    min = Math.min(...positiveNumbers);
    
    return `El numero menor es ${min}`;
  }
};


console.log(setNumbers());
```